# Apache Camel route: onCompletion not reached when exception occurs?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a Camel route that looks something like the one below.  If all records parse successfully, then I get an email from the onCompletion  step.  If one record gets an exception then the rest of the records will process, which is fine, but  the onCompletion step does not fire.

What I'd like is for the onCompletion  step to run even if there are errors and to be able to send a message saying "route completed with errors".  How can I do this?

```
        <route id="route1">
            <from uri="file://C:/TEMP/load?noop=true&amp;idempotentRepository=#sysoutStore&amp;sorter=#externalDataFilesSorter"/>
            <choice>
                <when>
                    <simple>${file:name} regex '*file.*.(txt)'</simple>
                    <to uri="direct:RouteFile" />
               </when>
            </choice>      
        </route>

        <route id="testRouteDirect">
            <from uri="direct:RouteFile" />
                <onException>
                    <exception>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException</exception>
                    <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="1" />
                    <handled>
                        <constant>true</constant>
                     </handled>
                    <to uri="log:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"></to>
                </onException> 
                <onException>
                    <exception>java.text.ParseException</exception>
                    <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="1" />
                    <handled>
                        <constant>true</constant>
                     </handled>
                    <to uri="log:java.text.ParseException"></to>
                </onException> 
                <split parallelProcessing="false" strategyRef="exchangePropertiesAggregatorStrategy" >
                    <tokenize token="\r\n"/>
                    <to uri="log:Record"></to>
                </split>
              <onCompletion>
                    <to uri="log:completion"></to> 
                    <to uri="smtp://mail.com?contentType=text/html&amp;to=done@test.com&amp;from=route@test.com&amp;subject=we're done" />
              </onCompletion>
        </route>
```

Comment: Surround the processing part in a doTry() and doCatch(). The records that failed will be caught and then you can decide to log them or do something else with them. The route will continue processing so it should trigger the OnCompletion.

Comment: The `onCompletion` should fire regardless of an exception. Perhaps an  an exception occurs prior to the cbr block in the first route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of tickets related to oncompletion on the camel site: [Camel Jira URL](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-3372?jql=text%20~%20%22oncompletion%22).  I upgraded to a newer version of camel & I don't get this issue any more.

Answer (score 1):

The best part of your route is, you have onException inside your route with handled=true. So move your onCompletion to the parent route(route1), It should work !